# SQL script to update records, removing duplicated content from within the field

Tags: sql, apostrophe

I have a situation that has arisen with an errant SQL stored procedure, and am now facing a potentially daunting task of data clean-up.

The long and short of it is that we have data in our database that may have any number of repeated apostrophes.  So, the data may look like:

```
"This is a comment"
"This comment is OK, but it's not affected"
"This comment''s text has a doubled apostrophe"
"This comment''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''s text has numerous doubled apostrophes"
```

As such, we can easily look for rows WHERE Comment LIKE '%''''%' to find the errant data, but is there any way to create an UPDATE script that can deal with these all in one fell swoop?

I'm hopeful, but not expectant.  I'm hoping it won't be a painful task to do manually, but hey' I'm lazy at heart :-)

Comment: MySQL has RLIKE and REGEXP, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I would find the collection with a query and replace the bad data with a single 'replace' function if these are always a fixed length.  If there is more to it you can use a charindex to find patterns to look for and replace.  Generally for mass replace I do a test of the logic when I want to do a self update.

Here is a simple example with a table variable:

```
declare @Table table ( data varchar(32) );

insert into @Table values ('stut""""""'),('stu""""""');

select 
    *
,   replace(data, '""""""', '')
from @Table

update @Table 
set data = replace(data, '""""""', '')

select *
from @Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a character unrepresented in your text such as Char(0), here is pseudocode:

```
UPDATE Yourtable
SET Col = Replace(Replace(Replace("'", Char(0) + "'"), "'" + Char(0), ""), Char(0), "")
WHERE Col LIKE "%''%"
```

This will turn any number of repetitions of a single quote into just one. I don't know your DBMS or I could try to give the exact syntax.

I am aware my double quotes above must be single quotes for most DBMSes.